# WSGIの例で出る関数で使われる引数environが何か知りたい

Tags: python, http

### はじめに

現在、WerkzeugというPythonで書かれたユーティリティライブラリの[チュートリアル](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/tutorial/)をやっているのですが、WSGIについて紹介された関数について理解仕切れていません。

### 分からないところ

```
def application(environ, start_response):

    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/plain')])

    return ['Hello, world']
```

上記のapplication関数は、下記3点からWSGIアプリケーションの要点を満たしている(by [WSGI - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface))ようなのですが、

- WSGIアプリケーションは、callableオブジェクト (__call__が定義されたオブジェクト) として定義する（この例では application 関数）。このオブジェクトが呼び出される際、引数 environ としてCGIと同様の環境変数が渡され、引数 start_response として、ステータスコードとレスポンスヘッダを受け取るcallableオブジェクトが渡される。
- start_response を呼び出して、ステータスコードとレスポンスヘッダを設定する。
- WSGIアプリケーションの戻り値は、本文を生成するiteratableオブジェクトである必要がある。

ここで『`environ`がCGIと同様の環境変数である』、というのはどういうことなのでしょうか？CGIとはCommon Gateway Interfaceのことだと思っているのですが、[Perlの$ENV{...}](https://perl.misty.ne.jp/21.html)のようにアクセス情報やブラウザ情報が入る何か...ということなのでしょうか？

またこの`environ`が関数の中で何か役割を果たしているようには見えないのですが`environ`はどう活きるのでしょうか？

質問が抽象的になってしまい申し訳ないのですが、どなたか教えていただけると幸いです。

### 追記

上記のapplicationをwsgiref.simple_serverの第三引数に入れて使われているのを確認したのですが、ここでもenvironが使われているようではありませんでした。
※[公式ドキュメント/シンプルな WSGI HTTP サーバ](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref.simple_server)
※[技評/WSGIの概要](https://gihyo.jp/dev/feature/01/wsgi/0001)

Comment: この記事 [WSGIアプリケーションのリクエスト情報の取得を実装する](https://qiita.com/sti320a/items/f20b8cbc06bf70425d33) とか、そこから参照されてるPEP 3333の [environ Variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#environ-variables) とかが参考になりそうです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問を書いている時間で

```py
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    yield str(environ).encode()
```

などとして動かしてみればすぐわかることです。

例えばuwsgiで動かせば

```
{'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
'REQUEST_URI': '/',
'PATH_INFO': '/',
'QUERY_STRING': '',
'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
'SCRIPT_NAME': '',
'SERVER_NAME': 'xxxxxx',
'SERVER_PORT': '9090',
'UWSGI_ROUTER': 'http',
'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
'REMOTE_PORT': '4075',
'HTTP_HOST': 'localhost:9090',
'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'xxxxxx',
'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'ja,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate',
'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive',
'HTTP_COOKIE': 'xxxxxx',
'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS': '1',
'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0',
'wsgi.input': <uwsgi._Input object at 0x10340e210>,
'wsgi.file_wrapper': <built-in function uwsgi_sendfile>,
'wsgi.version': (1, 0),
'wsgi.errors': <_io.TextIOWrapper name=2 mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>,
'wsgi.run_once': False,
'wsgi.multithread': False,
'wsgi.multiprocess': False,
'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
'uwsgi.version': b'2.0.19.1',
'uwsgi.node': b'xxxxxx'}
```

gunicornで動かせば

```
{'wsgi.errors': <gunicorn.http.wsgi.WSGIErrorsWrapper object at 0x10b881310>, 
'wsgi.version': (1, 0), 
'wsgi.multithread': False, 
'wsgi.multiprocess': False, 
'wsgi.run_once': False, 
'wsgi.file_wrapper': <class 'gunicorn.http.wsgi.FileWrapper'>, 
'wsgi.input_terminated': True, 
'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'gunicorn/20.0.4', 
'wsgi.input': <gunicorn.http.body.Body object at 0x10b8812d0>, 
'gunicorn.socket': <socket.socket fd=9, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 8000), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 60283)>, 
'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 
'QUERY_STRING': '', 
'RAW_URI': '/', 
'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1', 
'HTTP_HOST': 'localhost:8000', 
'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'xxxxxx', 
'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 
'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'ja,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3', 
'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate', 
'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive', 
'HTTP_COOKIE': 'xxxxxx, 
'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS': '1', 
'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0', 
'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http', 
'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1', 
'REMOTE_PORT': '60283', 
'SERVER_NAME': '127.0.0.1', 
'SERVER_PORT': '8000', 
'PATH_INFO': '/', 
'SCRIPT_NAME': ''}
```

と出ます。
（読みやすいように改行して不要な情報を置き換えてます）

どうやって起動されているか? どうやって呼び出されたか? 呼び出されたアプリケーションはどこから情報を得てどこに情報を渡せばいいか? といった情報を**すべてひっくるめて**環境（environment)と呼んでいると分かると思います。

このうちのいくつかはアプリケーションを書く人が使うかもしれない情報で、いくつかはWSGIアプリケーションコンテナが必要としているから保管してある情報です。

逆に言うと、それらを区別することなく一つの辞書にまとめて入れているから、環境というふわっとした言葉を選ばざるをえないのかな、と感じます。

---

> またこのenvironが関数の中で何か役割を果たしているようには見えないのですが

"どんなリクエストが来ようとも**一切気にせず**固定の結果を返すアプリケーション"なのだから当然です。

Answer (score 0):

よくよく[Werkzeugのドキュメント](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/tutorial/)を確認してみると、

"The environ contains all incoming information, the start_response function can be used to indicate the start of the response."
『environ には全ての受信情報が含まれており、start_response 関数はレスポンスの開始を示すために使用されます。』(拙訳)

と書いてありました。わかったようなわからないような感じはまだありますが...